# How to use another function to display output of a function in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    joining_date date,
    employee_type character varying,
    name character varying 
);
insert into employee VALUES
    (NULL,'as','hjasghg'),
    ('2022-08-12', 'Rs', 'sa'),
  (NULL,'as1','hjasghg1'),
    ('2024-09-12', 'Rs1', 'sa1'),
  (NULL,'as2','hjasghg2'),
    ('2023-12-12', 'Rs2', 'sa2'),
    (NULL,'asktyuk12','hjasg21');
```

This is a dummy table, what I have are two functions, one gives employee_type and name if I use fn_search(name) and other gives a list of names and joining_date accessible by loginid fn_login(loginid). I want to use fn_login(loginid) and create a fn_search(name, loginid). I have declared and assigned a variable `listname :=  fn_login(loginid)` in fn_search(name, loginid), what I want to know is what should I declare listname as text or record as it returns a row or sometimes more than one row. Also, how should I further use that to generate data only if the logind of user can access this record.

Answer (score 0):

setup:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    loginid bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    joining_date date,
    employee_type text,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO employee (joining_date, employee_type, name)
    VALUES (NULL, 'as', 'hjasghg'), ('2022-08-12', 'Rs', 'sa'),
    (NULL, 'as1', 'hjasghg1'),      ('2024-09-12', 'Rs1', 'sa1'),
    (NULL, 'as2', 'hjasghg2'),      ('2023-12-12', 'Rs2', 'sa2'),
    (NULL, 'asktyuk12', 'hjasg21');
```

---

fn_login function, it can return more than 1 row

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_login (IN _loginid bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        _name text,
        _joining_date date
    )
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN query
    SELECT
        name,
        joining_date
    FROM
        employee
    WHERE
        loginid >= _loginid;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

> what I want to know is what should I declare listname as text or
> record as it returns a row or sometimes more than one row

`listname :=  fn_login(loginid)`, you want do more compute with `listname`, then you need loop through `listname`.
follow/imitate manual example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING come with following function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_search (IN _name text, IN _loginid bigint)
    RETURNS void
    AS $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    i int := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            fn_login (_loginid))
        LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE '[%] rec._name: %, rec._joining_date: %', i, rec._name, rec._joining_date;
            IF rec._joining_date IS NULL THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'fn_login join_date is null';
            END IF;
            i := i + 1;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```